# How to create SQL table with columns corresponding to dates

Tags: teradata

So I currently have a Teradata SQL table which has rows for each person & date combination.

For example, my table currently looks like

```
Person 1, 11/10/2014, Y
Person 1, 11/05/2015, N
Person 2, 10/01/2013, Y
```

Is there a way to transform this table in SQL so that I instead have the form

```
  10/01/2013 11/05/2015 11/10/2014
1 O           N           Y
2 Y           O           O
```

where each person has a row and each date has its own column? The `O` entries represent rows where there is neither a Y or N.

I've tried pivot and transform to no avail. Much help is appreciated.

Comment: can u please paste the piece of code you have written

Answer (score 0):

use [TD_UNPIVOT](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_14_10/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1145_112A/Table_Operators.098.27.html#ww14402805) if you have Teradata version >= 14.10